# Verifying that $\sqrt{(R+j\omega L)(j\omega C)}=0.5\frac{R}{\sqrt{L/C}}+j\omega\sqrt{LC}$ for $R\lll \omega L$

Tags: complex-numbers, radicals

So I have the following square root of this two complex numbers and my book provides this:

$$\sqrt{(R+j\omega L)(j\omega C)}=0.5\frac{R}{\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}}+j\omega\sqrt{LC}$$

if $$R\lll\omega L$$

I have no freaking idea how they do this mathematically. I tried to apply distributive property, which leads to

$$\sqrt{jR\omega C-\omega^2LC}$$

And the second term of my expansion kind of looks like the second term of the expression 
$$\sqrt{-\omega^2LC}=j\omega\sqrt{LC}$$

But I don't if (a) this is correct and (b) how do I get the first term.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic idea is that $\sqrt{1+x} \approx 1+\frac x2$ when $x \ll 1$.  The right side is the first two terms of the Taylor series.  If you expand the left you have 
$$\sqrt{(R+j\omega L)(j\omega C)}=\sqrt{Rj\omega C-\omega^2LC}\\
=j\omega\sqrt{LC}\sqrt {R\frac 1{j\omega L}+1}\\
\approx j\omega \sqrt{LC}\left(1+\frac {R}{2j\omega L}\right)\\
=j\omega \sqrt{LC}+\frac R2\sqrt{\frac {C}{L}}$$
They owe you an approximation sign when they do the Taylor series step.

Comment: "They owe you an approximation sign when they do the Taylor series step." - It looks like it's from a physics book. Allowances must be made... :)

Comment: @Matthias:  Actually the $j$ indicates it is probably engineering.  I was a physics student and remember getting the approximation signs, but it was many years ago.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation Ross! I forgot about the Taylor series. It is from an engineering book indeed